# Secure Node API for React Front End

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, security

I’m building a `React` application with a `Node` backend. In the backend I have an `API` that just talks to a database and I can deploy the `API` and the `React` app at the same time.

Although this works fine, the `API` routes are not secure ,i.e, anyone can freely access `myapp.com/api/getData`. I would like only my `React` front end to be able to access these /`API` endpoints and I’m not sure what is the best way to do that.

To be clear, I don’t mean securing them so that only a logged in user can access them but basically preventing a user from going in their `browser` / `Postman`, typing in that `URL` and getting the data.

I know that a solution would be to have the `API` as a separate project, deployed separately and secure that with an `API` key for example but I like the convenience of having both deployed at the same time.

Is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT: I've ended up just moving the API to a separate project

Comment: Do you consider using API key? For example, https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/when-why-api-key

Comment: @ChrisWong Yes, I have tried doing this but it means I need to store the API credentials in the front end which would make them publicly available as there is no way (as far as I know) to hide them in React.

Comment: @pawKer It's an interesting problem but I don't think there's a better way to do this.